# Verifying site ownership

Tags: php, url, registration, verification

First off, apologies about the silly question, but I could not find documentation on how to solve this problem.

I have a SaaS project, in which users have to register in order to user this service. This project is written in PHP.

Now, at one point during the registration, users have to submit their website url (because this SaaS solution is specific to the domain being registered by the user).

My question is after a user submits his/her website during registration, how do I verify that he/she is the owner of the site they say they own?

In case you are wondering, I have to verify this in order to prevent errors and prevent fraud.

Thanks.

Comment: This is not a good question for StackOverflow and will likely be closed. That said, I'd look at how Google verifies domain ownership (when you setup email hosting, for example). They require you to create a DNS record, or insert a meta tag into your website homepage.

Comment: Google Webmaster Tools used to ask you to put a `<meta>` tag with a specific identifier in your site's root page.

Comment: @jszobody - Why is it not a good question for StackOverflow?